# Date format string padding in an inexistant time

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

Currently parsing some date strings of this format:

```
[Sunday May 25, 2014, Monday May 26, 2014, Tuesday May 27, 2014, Wednesday May 28, 2014]
```

Looking at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), I have this formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMMM dd, yyyy");
pollenMap.put(format.parse(dates.text()), levels.text());
```

With that said, my inputs are now in this format:

```
[Sun May 25 00:00:00 EDT 2014, Mon May 26 00:00:00 EDT 2014, Tue May 27 00:00:00 EDT 2014, Wed May 28 00:00:00 EDT 2014]
```

As you can see, the dates are padded with `HH:mm:ss Z` times, which doesn't exist while in parsing. Another thing I noticed is the removal of the `,` afterwards.

Could this be an error of my `format` string being incorrect?

Comment: You've shown us how you _parse_ the dates? Where are you _formatting_ the dates? Also, if you already have the dates in the right format, why would you parse them into `Date` objects only to reformat them later?

Comment: Huh?  Your *input* format has changed; how could that be due to an error in your parsing code?

Comment: You are all too correct. I was a bit hasty in my implementation.

Comment: Do you still have a question? If so, please clarify.

Comment: I get what you guys are trying to say. `Date` is a date *and* a time. The way I am calling it, using the standard `.toString()` also returns the `time`. I simply need to change how I get the date. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse method will return a Date which then you said you used the toString to print the data. but in the documentation of toString of the Date class states that:

```
Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
 dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

it is not the formatting but the toString itself

Comment: Hmm. Would overriding the `toString` help?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage yes but it is a lot of work and you could also put the time in Calendar class